# css higher z-index appears under lower one

Tags: css, z-index

I'm struggling with a problem with z-indexes on css.

I have one item with z-index < 100, and another one (image)
with a z-index of 3000 (really a lot higher).

Still the second one appears under the first one, it drives me a little crazy.
I've searches a bit on the problem, I've read that it can be caused by not putting 
a position, so I've tried with position:fixed, position:relative, but none of the 2 work.

The website is:
www.imagine-that.be

The image has to appear at the bottom right, at the right side
of the menu. You can slightly see it behind the menu.

this is the css code that I try to use:

```
#menulogo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:40px;
    right:100px;
    z-index:2000;
}
#menulogo img {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:40px;
    right:100px;
    z-index:2000;
}
```

I really don't have a clue at the moment what I should do to solve this,
so any help will be appreciated big time!

regards,

Koen

Comment: When you do manage to fix this issue, people will not be able to click on the links underneath the image. EDIT: I have just moved it to my other monitor and the image will not cover any links. It will only affect people browsing in a smaller window.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) to learn how z-index works. To fix your issue, just parent your `div#menulogo` at the `body` element.

Comment: For those finding this at a later date the article URL is now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: @NSwanson7 thanks for providing the updated link. I edited the original answer to use the new URL.

Answer (score -3):

Change your code like this

```
#menulogo {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:40px;
    right:100px;
    z-index:2000;
}
#menulogo img {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:40px;
    right:100px;
    z-index:5000; //changed from 2000 to 5000
}
```

Comment: Doesn't explain the problem.