# Layering toast alerts above dialog modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, svelte, toast

When combining a [DaisyUI modal](https://daisyui.com/components/modal/) (a TailwindCSS UI library) with a [toast alert](https://github.com/zerodevx/svelte-toast) library, I can't seem to find any CSS that'll allow my global toast alerts to appear above the modal dialog (while just experimenting via the browser's DevTools).

I've tried:

- Various variations of `z-index` and `position` options for the components and their parents based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783812/css-higher-z-index-appears-under-lower-one) and the MDN article on [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context).
- Also changing the ordering and placement of the components and their parents in my larger app (while still keeping my alerting mechanism in a "global" location), but I found the same problem in the minimal example below.
- I also found I could investigate with Chrome's DevTool's "[Layers](https://blog.logrocket.com/eliminate-content-repaints-with-the-new-layers-panel-in-chrome-e2c306d4d752/?gi=cd6271834cea)" tool (and Edge's [3D View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/whats-new/2019/12/devtools#3d-view)), but it didn't seem to give me any clear reasoning for which layers are above the others beyond saying that it "Overlaps other composited content".

The only thing I found that *did work*, was if I change the location of the dialog in the live webpage by using drag & drop in the DevTools Inspector. That immediately moves all the toast alerts above the dialog regardless of where I move the dialog, but I don't know how to make use of that.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Layer test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.7.3/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>  
  <!-- Load `toast` and `SvelteToast` into global scope  -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@zerodevx/svelte-toast@0.9.5"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button class="btn" onclick="my_modal_1.showModal()">open modal</button>
<dialog id="my_modal_1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-box">
    <h3 class="font-bold text-lg">Hello!</h3>
    <p class="py-4">Press ESC key or click the button below to close</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toast.push('Alert!', {  initial: 0 })">Trigger alert!</button>
    <div class="modal-action">
      <form method="dialog">
        <button class="btn">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<script>
    const toastApp = new SvelteToast({
      target: document.body,
      props: {
        options: {
            reversed: true,
            intro: { y: 192 },
        }
      }
    })
</script>

<style>
    /* Style to put alerts in bottom middle. */
    :root {
        --toastContainerTop: auto;
        --toastContainerRight: auto;
        --toastContainerBottom: 1rem;
        --toastContainerLeft: calc(50vw - 8rem);
    }
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems HTML has a [relatively recent](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/top-layer-devtools/) concept of a [top layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Top_layer) which is:

> a specific layer that spans the entire width and height of the viewport and sits on top of all other layers displayed in a web document

and therefore supersedes any z-index and other layering tried in the standard document. It gets used specifically for [<dialog>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) elements that use [HTMLDialogElement.showModal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal), as well as [Popover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/showPopover) and [Fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) elements.

The only way to get the toast alerts to appear above the modal is to **also place it within such a top layer**. The easiest to do it would be to also place them within the dialog used by the modal.

That might not seem ideal if you want your alerts to be globally visible even when the modal is not open, but the toast library used seems to have a single store of all toasts, which means that multiple overlapping toast display areas can be created, and you'll still only need to close them once. See for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Layer test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@3.7.3/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>  
  <!-- Load `toast` and `SvelteToast` into global scope  -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@zerodevx/svelte-toast@0.9.5"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button class="btn" onclick="my_modal_1.showModal()">open modal</button>
<dialog id="my_modal_1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-box">
    <h3 class="font-bold text-lg">Hello!</h3>
    <p class="py-4">Press ESC key or click the button below to close</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toast.push('Alert!', { initial: 0 })">Trigger alert!</button>
    <div class="modal-action">
      <form method="dialog">
        <button class="btn">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<script>
    const dialog = document.getElementById("my_modal_1");
    const toastProps = {
      options: {
          reversed: true,
          intro: { y: 192 },
      }
    };
    /*
      Attach to 2 different areas: one for global alerts and the
      other for alerts that happen while the dialog is showing.
    */
    const toastApp = new SvelteToast({
      target: document.body,
      props: toastProps
    });
    const toastDialog = new SvelteToast({
      target: dialog,
      props: toastProps
    });
</script>

<style>
    /* Style to put alerts in bottom middle. */
    :root {
        --toastContainerTop: auto;
        --toastContainerRight: auto;
        --toastContainerBottom: 1rem;
        --toastContainerLeft: calc(50vw - 8rem);
    }
</style>
</body>

</html>
```